# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 at Calculator.main(Calculator.java:25)

Tags: java

I wrote this code for a simple calculator and I get this error! Someone help me please!

```
public class Calculator { 

  public static void main (String[] args) {

    int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    int num2 = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    int sum = num1 + num2;
    int sub = num1 - num2;  
    int prod = num1 * num2;
    int quot = num1 / num2;
    int rem = num1 % num2;

    // print the other variables, sub, prod, quot, rem;     
    System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + sum);      
    System.out.println(num1 + " - " + num2 + " = " + sub);      
    System.out.println(num1 + " * " + num2 + " = " + prod);     
    System.out.println(num1 + " / " + num2 + " = " + quot);     
    System.out.println(num1 + " % " + num2 + " = " + rem);
  }
}
```

Comment: `Java != JavaScript` ;)

Comment: How are you calling `main`?

Comment: I suggest adding `if (args.length != 2) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected 2 arguments, but got: " + Arrays.toString(args))` to the start of your main-method. This won't fix your problem, but will give you a better error message ;-).

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that when the application is started, it is passed two strings that can be parsed as numbers  because your code assumes that `arguments` will have an element at positions `0` and `1`. If you don't pass two arguments, then you will get your error.

For example, if calling `main` from within the program:

```
Calculator.main(new String[] {"10","20"});
```

Or, if calling `Calculator.class` from the command line:

```
java Calculator 10 20
```

Comment: You don't typically call main directly. It's passed at the command line

Comment: @cricket_007 I know, I was just trying to reinforce the point and was adding the command line example at that moment.

Comment: But if I do that, then I get more errors?

Comment: @K.Lujan Ok, then there are other issues with your code that need to be worked out. Take them one at a time.

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks. I'm not a Java guy (I do C#), so I knew what the problem was, but a little rusty on the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

As the exception indicates, your program encountered an Array out of bounds exception when it tried to access an array within index of 0. The only place in your code above where in Array with an index of 0 is being accessed is at the following line

`int num1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);`

So in other words,  your program couldn't find 0th index of the args array which means you haven't passed any arguments to your program. Looks like your program two arguments in fact.  Run your program the following way if you are using command line

`java Calculator 100 200`